# Algebra of endomorphisms with minimal polynomial of bounded rank

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, representation-theory, matrix-rank

Let $k$ be a Natural number. I want to show that for $N \gg k$ there does not exist a subalgebra $\alpha \subset \mathrm{End}( \mathbb{C}^N)$ of dimension $\ge N$ such that every $\varphi \in \alpha$ has minimal polynomial of degree $\le k$ and no elements of rank $1$ (hence also no elements of corank $1$).

My idea is that such an algebra due to the hypothesis on the minimal polynomial must contain two non commuting endomorphisms. My intuition is that the minimal polynomial of the product should be more complicated (maybe one can prove that its degree increases?) . But I couldn`t work it out.

Notice that the bound on the dimension of the algebra may be far from being optimal and maybe even indipendent from $N$ a priori. My understanding of the problem is so limited that to me it can even be $k^2$ or being completely false.
As far as I understand the hypothesys on the rank may be useless.

Comment: I assume you have first worked through the case $k=1$?

Comment: Thank you. The case $k=1$ is the only easy one as then you get $\alpha =<id>$ (maybe I forgot to mention that for me a subalgebra always contains the identity). The case $k=2$ would be already interesting for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok this took me a while but your claim is actually false. Let $N = 4t$, and first consider the rng(ring without identity)
$$B = \begin{bmatrix}0 & X & 0 & 0 
\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & X 
\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
 \end{bmatrix}, X \in M_t(\mathbb{C}).$$
Note that the shape of $B$ guarantees that the product of any two elements of $B$ is $0$. Furthermore, any nonzero element of $B$ has rank at least $2$.

Now let $A = \mathbb{C} I + B$. Then $A$ is an algebra, every element of $A$ has minimal polynomial of degree at most $2$, and no element of $A$ has rank $1$. But the dimension of $A$ is $t^2 + 1 > N$, for $t\ge 4$.

Comment: (for $t \ge 4$). Good (counter)example already for the case $k=2$.

Comment: Thank you, very nice! Now I would like to know if the result may hold with an extra hypothesis (i.e. there are no $k$ endomorphisms $\varphi_1,\dots,\varphi_k$ with the following properties: $\mathrm{rank}(\varphi_i)>\mathrm{rank}(\varphi_{i+1})$, $\mathrm{Im }(\varphi_{i+1})\subset\mathrm{Im}(\varphi_{i})$, $\mathrm{ker }(\varphi_i)\subset\mathrm{ker}(\varphi_{i+1})$. Do you think that your counterexample may be adapted also to this case somehow?